# How long does it take to get a Canadian student visa?

Tags: visa, canada, student-visa

I have just received an offer letter from Canada for my student visa. How long would it take for me to receive the visa if I apply today? Also, how much earlier than the intake time (September) would I be able to enter the country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the application processing times for every kind of application [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/). It depends on which country you are applying from. Also you might want to check the document checklist for applying a student visa [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5483E.pdf).

You can enter Canada on the first day of your Visa approval i.e. the date of issue which is written on the visa that you get on the passport.